# Issue regarding login flow

Tags: react-native, authentication, go, oauth-2.0

I am working on an application that has a backend writen in Go (I am using Gin-Gonic/Gothic). I managed to implement an endpoint /login/google that starts the login process (redirects to google official login page), and after a successful login I have set the redirect request from the google to be on my /login/google/callback function. It works, I can get all the details from the logged user, but now I want to make a client application with react-native(and expo) with a simple page with a login button, that when pressed starts the backend logic of login. The thing is that I don't know how to redirect from the callback function back to the client application after succesfull login

I tried to make the flow with the client side only but I don't thing is a good idea.

Go functions use for the /login/google and /login/google/callback are the following:

```
func (auth *AuthAPI) BeginAuth(c *gin.Context) {
q := c.Request.URL.Query()
provider := c.Param("provider")
q.Add("provider", provider)
c.Request.URL.RawQuery = q.Encode()

url, err := gothic.GetAuthURL(c.Writer, c.Request)
if err != nil {
    c.AbortWithError(http.StatusInternalServerError, err)
    return
}

data := gin.H{
    "redirectUrl": url,
}

c.JSON(200, data)}
```

And the callback function:

```
func (auth *AuthAPI) CompleteAuth(c *gin.Context) {
q := c.Request.URL.Query()
provider := c.Param("provider")
q.Add("provider", provider)
c.Request.URL.RawQuery = q.Encode()

user, err := gothic.CompleteUserAuth(c.Writer, c.Request)
if err != nil {
    c.AbortWithError(http.StatusInternalServerError, err)
    return
}
//Just an example, this might be moved to a business logic layer
//check if the auth method is already registered
var user_id = user.UserID
var user_provider = user.Provider
count := auth.database_connection.QueryRow("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM auth WHERE id = $1 AND method = $2", user_id, user_provider)

var user_count int
err = count.Scan(&user_count)
if err != nil {
    c.AbortWithStatus(http.StatusNotFound)
    slog.Warn("User not found", "user", user_id, "err", err)
    return
}

//insert the user and auth
if user_count == 0 {

    var new_user_id int
    err := auth.database_connection.QueryRow("INSERT INTO users (username, email) VALUES ($1, $2) RETURNING id", user.Name, user.Email).Scan(&new_user_id)
    if err != nil {
        c.AbortWithError(http.StatusInternalServerError, err)
        return
    }

    _, err = auth.database_connection.Exec("INSERT INTO auth (id, method, user_id) VALUES ($1, $2, $3)", user_id, user_provider, new_user_id)
    if err != nil {
        c.AbortWithError(http.StatusInternalServerError, err)
        return
    }
}
//get auth and create jwt

token, err := generateJWT(user.UserID)
if err != nil {
    c.AbortWithError(http.StatusInternalServerError, err)
}

claims, err := parseJWT(token)
if err != nil {
    c.AbortWithError(http.StatusInternalServerError, err)
}

c.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{"token": token,
    "claims": claims})}
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.